# Identify state depending on one or more log lines

Tags: transactions, state, splunk

I have logs for file imports

```
01-01-21 10:00:00  File Read   , filename_a
01-01-21 10:00:01  File failed , filename_a
01-01-21 10:00:01  File Read   , filename_b
01-01-21 10:00:02  File failed , filename_a
01-01-21 10:00:03  File succeed, filename_a
01-01-21 10:00:04  File failed , filename_b
```

how can I detect that file "a" has been successfully imported, while file "b" is in a failure mode?

I've tried  `transaction` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the status and filename fields extracted, select the most recent event for each file.  That will tell you the current status.

```
index=foo
| rex "File (?<status>\w+)\s*, (?<filename>.*)
| dedup filename
```

Comment: dedup selects the most recent event?

Comment: `dedup` selects the first event, which usually is the most recent since Splunk processes events in reverse time order.